# Blender has a problem with my GPU

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu

My GPU supports open cl (it's a Radeon R9 M375) it should render scenes just fine but blender pretends like it can't do it and it doesn't show up in preferences 
BUT when I use SHEEPIT render farm program the version of blender it uses to render, recognizes my GPU and it works just fine
I tried most things I thought could work like Radeon Pro Render or using Linux but none of them worked
Is this a bug or my GPU have a problem?

other details:
Lenovo Z51-70
i7-5500U
8GB Ram
Radeon R9 M375 4GB
Using Blender Version 2.92

Answer (score 1):

From [Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html)

HIP is enabled for GPU rendering with AMD graphics cards on Windows. Blender supports GPU rendering on discrete graphics cards with the AMD RDNA architecture or newer and AMD Radeon Software 21.12.1 or AMD Radeon PRO Software 21.Q4 GPU drivers or newer.

Support GPUs include:

AMD Radeon RX 5000 Series

AMD Radeon RX 6000 Series

AMD Radeon Pro W6000 Series